# ActionFilterAttribute for Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, authorization, action-filter

I need to implement some authorization mechanism in my application. The authorization is based on object which are sent from client to serwer. Every action in a controller take as an argument List. Based on nested property of objects in this list I have to grant or deny access to controller action. My first approach was to use custom filter attribute

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : FilterAttribute,IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //SOME LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

However, because of the fact that the request is json request, it is hard for me to get values of every relevant property of sent objects (I have only acces to json values). That is why I thought that I could use ActionFilterAttribute instead of FilterAttribute.

```
 public class ActionFilterAuthorization: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var castedList = filterContext.ActionParameters["key"] as List<MyObject>;
        //logic here 

       //throw exception is access is not granted

    }
}
```

The question is if this is good solution for authorization? Maybe it would be better to check authorization inside of actions ??

Answer (score 1):

Security is a [cross cutting concern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232768.aspx) so Filters and Attributes are ideal places for it. Having to check it manually in every action would add a lot of extra code that had to be maintained and adds to security risk if it is forgotten. Making it a global filter would mean it would always be applied which means you could write an attribute that perhaps exempted an Action/Controller if they didn't need it e.g. AllowAnnoymous etc [enter link description here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx).

Best general article on security I have found for MVC3 is this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288631/Secure-ASP-NET-MVC3-applications